# Listening to scheduled jobs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a listener to a specific job (I didn't design or write) running in Eclipse.
I know I can get access to the [Job Manager](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/IJobManager.html) using [Job.getJobManager](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.html#getJobManager). Inside IJobManager there's the method [find](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/IJobManager.html#find) but it requires a family object.

The [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_whether_a_particular_job_is_running%3F) also presumes that you know the family object. How can I find the current list of family objects used in a given job manager?

Or is my only option to register a [JobChangeListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/IJobChangeListener.html) and filter out the job(s) I'm interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add minor changes to your jobs, use OSGI events to communicate between them. Asume, you have a job like that:

```
public class SomeJob extends Job {
    public static final JOB_EVENT_NAME = "some distinct name";
    private IEventBroker eventBroker;
    public SomeJob(IEventBroker eventBroker) {
        super("SomeJob");
        this.eventBroker = eventBroker;
    }
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        ...
        eventBroker.post(JOB_EVENT_NAME, some data);
        ...
    }
}
```

Start it from RCP application with event listener attached (eventBroker is IEventBroker and can be @Inject'ed):

```
new CheckAccessLevelJob(eventBroker).schedule();
eventBroker.subscribe(SomeJob.JOB_EVENT_NAME, new EventHandler() {
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.getProperty(IEventBroker.DATA);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't touch the jobs that I need to listen to. I didn't write them and I don't have the source

Comment: Btw, most jobs do not use families. So, you can find them with null family object: Platform.getJobManager().find(null).